# Upgraded pgAdmin shows warning, not displaying Tables list, queries working without problem

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, pgadmin-4

I upgraded my local Postgresql test server to PostgreSQL15 today morning.
Opening pgAdmin gave me a warning that some of the features may not work correctly because I have a server with version 9 added to pgAdmin.

Steps done:

1. Upgraded Postgresql v14 to v15.
2. PgAdmin shows warnings and couldn't see the tables list.
3. Uninstalled v15 and installed v14. Again the same issue.
4. Uninstalled v14 and get v12 of Postgresql.

- Clean uninstall was done by removing the Postgresql folder from the "ProgamFiles" folder and  "AppData/Roaming"

Current situation:

Still, pgAdmin is not showing the list of tables for the older server version (v9).
I cannot upgrade this server, but have to use it in PgAdmin as before.
But I can run the all queries without any problem.

When adding the V9 server, pgAdmin shows a warning like this
[image: Warning messages]

It is listing up all schemas, views, and sequences. But when clicking the Tables, it keeps loading and never gives the list of tables.

[image: Clicking Tables issue]

By the way, I am using Windows 10 64bit OS.

After five days, I degraded my Postgresql to V12 and now getting an error like this:

```
ERROR: column "wait_event_type" does not exist LINE 10: wait_event_type || ': ' || wait_event AS wait_event, ^ 
enter code here
```

Have anybody gone through such an issue? Need some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form. Also, please explain how this is related to programming

Comment: You will need to install an older pgAdmin version in addition to the most recent version if you want to access unsupported Postgres versions.

Comment: I hope so. But I have been using pgAdmin4 (the same version as of now) without any issues. I even had Postgresql V9.2 added to that